# C# VSTO Addin Exception With CurrentItem

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

When trying to obtain the current item with focus in an outlook 2013 addin I get this exception: An exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in System.Dynamic.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error while invoking [PROPERTYGET, DISPID(0)].

The code throwing the exception is this:

```
Inspector curObj = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
Object curItem = curObj.CurrentItem();
```

The second line throws the exception.  The addin is launched from a button on the ribbon when in the create message window.

What is the proper way to access the current item as I think I'm doing it wrong which is causing the issue, since it's saying CurrentItem is not a member.  The VBA code examples do it similar to this, but in C# CurrentItem doesn't seem to work the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CurrentItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869722.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a property, not a method.